По какому правилу расставлены запятые?
"В процессе зачатия, при слиянии яйцеклетки и сперматозоида, формируется единая клетка".
Проверяю перевод и вижу вот такое выделение запятыми. По какому правилу переводчик их так расставил? В оригинале пояснения нет. Спасибо.

Правильно:
В процессе зачатия, при слиянии яйцеклетки и сперматозоида, формируется единая клетка.
Второе обстоятельство со значением времени имеет уточняющее значение и обособляется.
Обособлению дополнительно способствует распространенность оборота.
В общем случае второе обстоятельство может быть как неоднородным (нет обособления), так и уточняющим.
Розенталь: Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными
 1. Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения могут 
 обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, 
 выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей 
 (обычно с предлогами).


Благодарю. Насколько я понял, вариант без обособления возможен, верно? Последний — самый распространенный вариант в переводах, которые я проверяю.

Да, оба варианта возможны. Выбор делается как по уточняющему смыслу (по семантике), так и по структуре предложения. В этом случае  второе обстоятельство  достаточно распространено.
